# cognos cache for story, dashboard and report

Tags: cognos-11

Q1:  If  I set  "Data cache  = On"  in  a dashboard or story,
What is the  default  cache  expire duration  for  story and dashboard ?  I don't see any thing about it in document. I need a number.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_ca_dshb.doc/ca_enable_data_caching.html

Q2:  If  I set  "use local  cache  = yes"  in a report ,
What is the default cache expire duration for report  ?
The document says  60 minutes， really ? where to modify it ?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.doc/c_queryreuse.html

Answer (score 0):

i know this isn't 100 % answer to your question but if you use data modules you can select a table in the module, open properties and under advanced modify data cache functionality.

[image]